# Averaging values between Pandas dataframes with keys existing in one and data in the other

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one of nodes connected to a 2 or 4 node element, and the other containing data about the nodes. I want average the data for the element based on the data of its connected nodes.

Here's the element dataframe. n1, n2, n3, n4 correspond to the nodes on that element
and eID is the element ID. The element can have either 2 or 4 nodes and could have blank "n" fields:

```
  eID   n1  n2  n3  n4
    0    1   4     
    1    4   1   
    2    2   7   3   6
    3    1   9   8   1
    4    3   4   6   3
```

The dataframe containing the nodal data. The nodeID column represents every node in any of the "n" columns in the element frame:

```
  nodeID        dx         dy        dz
    0    88.340153 -88.340153 23.234556
    1    66.370153 -66.370153 23.632464
    2    76.422513 -74.423513 11.245715
    3    22.333573 -32.328673 55.345354
    4    14.123763 -74.322413 14.637526
```

I want to have an average dx, dy, and dz for each element by simply averaging the nodal dx, dy, and dz for all the nodes on the element.

The desired element dataframe (i can just drop the n1, n2... columns once i have the data)

```
  eID       avg_dx     avg_dy    avg_dz
    0    88.340153 -88.340153 23.234556
    1    66.370153 -66.370153 23.632464
    2    76.422513 -74.423513 11.245715
    3    22.333573 -32.328673 55.345354
    4    14.123763 -74.322413 14.637526
```

what I've tried so far:

```
# col is the n1, n2, n3,n4
# node frame is the dataframe of nodal data.
for col in node_col_list: 
    element_node_relate = element_node_relate.merge(node_frame, left_on=col, right_index=True)

# drop _x and _y suffixes from merge
element_node_relate.columns = element_node_relate.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace('_x', ''))
element_node_relate.columns = element_node_relate.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace('_y', ''))

# drop "n" columns to just leave deflection data
element_node_relate = element_node_relate[[col for col in element_node_relate.columns if not regexn.match(col)]]

# final averaging of deflection data
element_node_relate = element_node_relate.groupby(element_node_relate.columns, axis=1).mean()

# apply "avg_" to columns to indicate averaged data
element_node_relate.columns = element_node_relate.columns.map(lambda x: "avg_" + x)
```

The problem I'm running into is, when I'm merging the frames, looping through the n columns and merging:

```
for col in node_col_list: # this is the n1, n2, n3,n4
    element_node_relate = element_node_relate.merge(node_frame, left_on=col, right_index=True)
```

my original element_node_relate dataframe is dropping data. i.e. the number of entries decreases each time by quite a bit. I'm not looking to drop entries where the "n" field is blank.

I'm hoping there's a an easier way to do this through pandas.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

khu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your two frames:

```
In [21]: df1
Out[21]: 
   eID  n1  n2  n3  n4
0    0   1   4 NaN NaN
1    1   4   1 NaN NaN
2    2   2   7   3   6
3    3   1   9   8   1
4    4   3   4   6   3

In [22]: df2
Out[22]: 
   nodeID         dx         dy         dz
0       0  88.340153 -88.340153  23.234556
1       1  66.370153 -66.370153  23.632464
2       2  76.422513 -74.423513  11.245715
3       3  22.333573 -32.328673  55.345354
4       4  14.123763 -74.322413  14.637526
```

Rather than looping and merging, I think a better approach would be to reshape df1 to 'long' format, using `melt`.

```
In [26]: df1_melt = pd.melt(df1, id_vars='eID').dropna()

In [27]: df1_melt
Out[27]: 
    eID variable  value
0     0       n1      1
1     1       n1      4
2     2       n1      2
3     3       n1      1
4     4       n1      3
5     0       n2      4
6     1       n2      1
7     2       n2      7
8     3       n2      9
9     4       n2      4
12    2       n3      3
13    3       n3      8
14    4       n3      6
17    2       n4      6
18    3       n4      1
19    4       n4      3
```

Then, from there, you can join against your other frame and summarize however you want.

```
In [28]: df1_merge = df1_melt.merge(df2, left_on='value', right_on='nodeID')

In [29]: df1_merge.groupby('eID')[['dx','dy','dz']].mean()
Out[29]: 
            dx         dy         dz
eID                                 
0    40.246958 -70.346283  19.134995
1    40.246958 -70.346283  19.134995
2    49.378043 -53.376093  33.295535
3    66.370153 -66.370153  23.632464
4    19.596970 -46.326586  41.776078
```